# What's the best way to run npm packages on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm

I'm new to rails and am using React for the front end. Ideally I would love to be able to go into my component and at the top, place an import statement like:

import npmpackage from 'npm-package'

It seems I cannot do that, and always get some kind of an error from rails when i try to run the server. I've heard the rails version that I'm using (5.1.3) allows for use of webpack, es6, and import statements like this.

Can anyone explain to me or maybe link me to a good guide on how this is done? Google seems to link me to unhelpful guides or outdated ones that use rails 4 or earlier.

this is my application.rb file:

```js
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Mediumrails
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules');
    config.load_defaults 5.1


    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
```

Comment: This link may help you. What i did is I added api.ai into rails app using webpack 

http://praaveenvr.blogspot.in/2017/08/rails-51-with-webpack-and-api-ai-sdk.html

Comment: This is github repo https://github.com/pvin/api.ai.client for the webpack with rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about (In Rails 5.1+):

```
rails new my-react-rails-app webpack=react
```

Or add `gem 'webpacker'` to `Gemfile` and bundle it. And then run `./bin/rails webpacker:install:react`
And just sit tight to give some time to rails to prepare everything :)

Maybe [this post](http://www.rony36.com/2017/08/24/rails-with-react.html) could be helpful.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I'm in the middle of this project currently so I think the webpacker gem might be better for me. After I run ./bin/rails webpacker:install:react , would I need to do anything else in order to say "import thispkg from 'this-package'" in my react jsx files?

Comment: Great to hear that :). Did you added `this-package` in `package.json`. Or try `yarn add this-package`? After adding any module need need to run `yarn`.

Comment: I ended up going with a fresh start and creating a rails app with react and webpack bundled in (no pun intended) by doing rails new project --webpack=react which seems to do exactly what i want it to do.